# $1$st order homogenous equation $xdy = (y -\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}) dx$

Tags: calculus, homogeneous-equation

$x\,dy = (y -\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})\,dx$

If I substitute $z(x)x$ over $y(x)$, where $z(x)$ is a new function,

then $dy = z\,dx + x\,dz$

I am doubting the way I am doing this is correct...

if $y(x) = z(x)x$ then the original equation would be $zy(z\,dx + x\,dz) = (xz -\sqrt{x^2 + x^2 z^2})\,dx$

Please help me to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Upon rearrangement, the terms cancel out, so that the integral is easier to solve. Take the x inside the square root, and express the terms in the form of y/x. Now, if you substitute y = (v)×(x), you'll see that it reduces to
    [dv/ √(1+v^2)] = -dx/x , and I hope you can take it from here.[image]

Comment: Why can't we substitude y with z?

Comment: It's all the same. You can use z if you want. It is a variable.

Comment: Could you please type here your solution because I don't really understand how to solve it?

Comment: I hope the attachment I had added is of help.

Comment: I don't think it's correct...

Comment: What mistake.  ?

Comment: I have a solution of another equation and it's different. 
Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/496XhGF

Comment: It's actually the same method, employed in a different manner. I did not multiply the 'dx' part with v, while in that link you had sent me, the 'dx' part has been multiplied with z. The thing is, it is a homogeneous differential equation. Which means if the equation canbe written in the form  dy/dx = f(y/x) or f(x/y) , you plug in y/x = z(x) or x/y = z(x). In the attachment, I have not yet completed the answer. I left it for you to complete.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
Write
$$\begin{align}
\alpha &= x \d y-y\d x + r \d x\\
\beta &= x^2+y^2-r^2\\
\gamma &= \d r+\d y
\end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
2x\alpha-2\d y\beta-(r-y)\d \beta &= 2r(r-y)\gamma \\
2(r+y)\alpha+2\d x\beta-x\d \beta &= 2rx\gamma
\end{align}$$
so that, if $r\neq 0$ and either $x\neq 0$ or $r\neq y$, then $\alpha\equiv 0$ and $\beta\equiv 0$ imply $\gamma\equiv 0$.